# How to simulate ramp-up with Locust?

Tags: locust

As I know Ramp-up function has been removed from locust.
Just wondering if the hatching process was the same as or similar to ramp-up? Or is there anyway to simulate the situation?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what ramp up function you are talking about. There are plenty of options for controlling ramp-up in locust, including the new step-load function:

```
  --step-load           Enable Step Load mode to monitor how performance
                        metrics varies when user load increases. Requires
                        --step-clients and --step-time to be specified.
  --step-clients STEP_CLIENTS
                        Client count to increase by step in Step Load mode.
                        Only used together with --step-load
  --step-time STEP_TIME
                        Step duration in Step Load mode, e.g. (300s, 20m, 3h,
                        1h30m, etc.). Only used together with --step-load
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. You can use custom load shapes for that.

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/custom-load-shape.html

This shape class will increase user count in blocks of 100 and then stop the load test after 10 minutes:

```py
class MyCustomShape(LoadTestShape):
    time_limit = 600
    spawn_rate = 20

    def tick(self):
        run_time = self.get_run_time()

        if run_time < self.time_limit:
            # User count rounded to nearest hundred.
            user_count = round(run_time, -2)
            return (user_count, spawn_rate)

        return None
```

Answer (score -2):

Just found a workaround by Taurus to schedule the load.